# Custom controller won't work in component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-controller

I have a custom controller that i know functions as i want it to. I say this because i can use {!var} on a visual force page and i get that value i want. However when i do the same thing in a component i cannot seem to get the value from the controller.

This doesn't work

```
<aura:component controller="AudioController">
    {!recURL}
</aura:component>
```

While this does

```
<apex:page controller="AudioController">
    {!recURL}
</apex:page>
```

Obviously i'm missing something pretty obvious here.

Answer (score 4):

This **won't work** because "a lightning component" and "a visualforce page" is not same as per their structure and their intent. They both follow different framework.

A VF (visual force) page is more "server centric" whereas a LC (lightning component) is more "UI centric". The way both communciate with server is different. While VF page interacts directly to the controller it's bind to and has access to the variables defined to be accessible through VF page, a LC always interacts to its controller through a JS layer and that the attributes need to be declared with annotation `@AuraEnabled`.

Take a look at the [Lightning Component Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm) and the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/units/lex_dev_lc_basics_prereqs) for more details on to get started with Lightning.

Also refer to how a LC interacts with server side components [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex.htm).

Answer (score 2):

It is normal that it does not work, lightning is not visualforce, you have not declared an attribute to use variable binding, you have not called your server side controller from your client side controller. You have not assinged values to your non existent variable.

I would strongly recommend you go  through
[Lightning Components Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics) in order to get familair with lightning development.

The following [Calling a Server-Side Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)  should give you a better understanding on calling server side action in lightning.